# Sharepoint List - Multiple Content Types - No Default Type?

Tags: 2010, list, content-type

I have a Sharepoint Calendar List that has multiple content types. When I click the "Add Item" link on the calendar, I am prompted to add information for the default content type. However, I want to be able to prompt the user as to which content type to fill out, without making them go to the New Item item in the ribbon. Is this possible in the 2010 Designer or the website?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use SharePoint Designer to edit the page. Remove the default "Add new item" link and add your own links (or buttons) for each content type. Then, for each of your links use the same javascript that your default link was using except append the content type id to the url.

For example:

```
&ContentTypeId=0x010600...long...ugly...hex...number
```

You can figure out what the content type ids are by clicking on the "Add new item" in the ribbon and looking in the address bar. In order to see the actual URL in the address bar of your browser, you will need to temporarily specify to not display forms in a dialog under List Settings > Advanced settings

Answer (score -1):

In List Settings, click Advanced Settings. Allow management of content types.

Then, the New button becomes a drop down, with an entry for each content type.

Comment: Since the list has multiple content types already, it's safe to assume that this option is already enabled. This question is asking about the "Add Item" link displayed below the list view, not the New button in the ribbon.